# Do I need to enable CSRF protection?

Tags: javascript, security, csrf

If none of the POST endpoints in my API server consume `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`, do I need to be concerned about CSRF?  From my understanding, CSRF can only be executed through form-backed POST requests.  Any other kind of request requires the use of `XMLHttpRequest`, which won't go through because of the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can [**send JSON from forms**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) in modern browsers. So everything that applies to `application/x-www-form-encoded` applies equally as much to other form data encoding types.

Moreoever - there is no guarantee support for more types won't be added in the future so there's always that.

Comment: When I say "modern browsers' it's more like beta branches and dev channels. As far as I'm aware the spec hasn't been integrated to the HTML5 standard yet. (text/plain is allowed though).

Comment: I see.  So it looks like although this avenue of attack isn't open today, it might be tomorrow; so I'll have to insure against it.